# Why is my Service Account Unable to Access GCP Projects?

Tags: cloud, bitbucket, devops, gcloud, bitbucket-pipelines

The service account integrated with Bitbucket is unable to `list` projects:

```sh
gcloud projects list

#=>

Listed 0 items.
```

or `set` `$MY_PROJECT`:

```sh
gcloud config set project $MY_PROJECT

#=>

Updated property [core/project].
```

*because* the output above is immediately followed by this warning:

> WARNING: You do not appear to have access to project [$MY_PROJECT] or it does not exist

The warning above contradicts the output of the following:

```sh
gcloud config list --format="value(core.project)"

#=>

$MY_PROJECT
```

Are there any missing steps or prerequisites in order to properly authorize this service account to `list` and `set` `$MY_PROJECT`?

My `bitbucket-pipelines.yaml` file:

```yaml
name: Test google auth
image: google/cloud-sdk:latest
script:
  - echo $KEY_FILE | base64 --decode --ignore-garbage > ~/google-key.json
  - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file ~/google-key.json
  - gcloud projects list
  - gcloud config set project $MY_PROJECT
  - gcloud container clusters get-credentials $MY_CLUSTER --region $REGION
services:
  - docker
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you successfully activate the service account as follows:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file service-account-key.json
```

and you can see it as the ACTIVE one after executing the following:

```
gcloud auth list
```

and still, get ZERO items

> Listed 0 items.

after executing the following:

```
gcloud projects list
```

**THEN**

Make sure to add your service account as a member to your **Organization** beside the project and assign it a **Viewer** role.

Answer (score 0):

What permissions do you set for the service account ? Did you add the below permission?

```
resourcemanager.projects.get
resourcemanager.projects.list
```

Comment: Can you double check if the authentication is correct when you run gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file ~/google-key.json`

Comment: What do you mean exaclty by correct? when i run gclud auth list it displayed the activated account which is the correct account

Comment: I think you are running this from the CI/CD pipeline, right? When you run the gcloud auth list in your local terminal, whether you use the same service account key? ~/google-key.json ? Because there can also be some error when your decode the key using base64

Comment: Actually when i run this on my local machine  `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file mykey.json` --------  I got this error ----------- `ERROR: (gcloud.auth.activate-service-account) There was a problem refreshing your current auth tokens: invalid_grant: Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values in the JWT claim.` -                                                                          
the file not encoded

Comment: That is why you are not able to list the project. I think you either need to create a new token file with the right permissions

Answer (score 0):

Check with `gcloud auth list` the active account that is using your Cloud SDK and then check also that it has the proper permissions on your project.

Comment: Yes - i have checked the active account and its permissions - but nothing - still the same

Comment: I would recommend you to add `echo` statements in your script to show the output of this commands as well your project environment variable `echo $MY_PROJECT`

Comment: Actually i already tried to echo each step and everything is good. :(

Comment: If you add reproduction steps I can take a look from my side.

Comment: The steps in the main post - or what exactly steps you need?

Comment: Where is your CI/CD pipeline being executed and how it is being done?

Answer (score 0):

The

> WARNING: You do not appear to have access to project [$PROJECT_ID] or it does not exist.

warning **will** appear *unless* there exists at least one role granted to the service account that contains the `resourcemanager.projects.get` permission.

Google Cloud accounts and permissions have an extra abstraction layer between them: *roles*.  You **cannot** grant permissions directly to a user or service account; you can *only* link users with roles and roles with permissions.  More on GCP roles [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles).

You need to either:

- Update at least one of the custom roles associated with the service account with the permissions listed above:

  ```sh
  gcloud iam roles update $ROLE \
  --add-permissions=resourcemanager.projects.get \
  --project=$PROJECT_ID

  #=>

  description: $ROLE_DESCRIPTION
  etag: . . .
  includedPermissions:
  . . .
  - resourcemanager.projects.get
  . . .
  name: projects/$PROJECT_ID/roles/$ROLE
  stage: . . .
  title: $ROLE_TITLE
  ```

  **Warning**: make sure to use the `--add-permissions` flag here when updating, as the `--permissions` flag will **remove** any other permissions the custom role used to have.
- Create a custom role:

  ```sh
  gcloud iam roles create $ROLE \
  --description="$ROLE_DESCRIPTION" \
  --permissions=resourcemanager.projects.get \
  --project=$PROJECT_ID \
  --title='$ROLE_TITLE'

  #=>

  Created role [$ROLE].
  description: $ROLE_DESCRIPTION
  etag: . . .
  includedPermissions:
  - resourcemanager.projects.get
  name: projects/$PROJECT_ID/roles/$ROLE
  stage: . . .
  title: $ROLE_TITLE
  ```

  and associate it with the service account:

  ```sh
  gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT_ID \
  --member=serviceAccount:$SERVICE_ACCOUNT \
  --role=projects/$PROJECT_ID/roles/$ROLE

  #=>

  Updated IAM policy for project [$PROJECT_ID].
  auditConfigs:
  . . .
  ```
- Associate the service account with a curated role that already contains the `resourcemanager.projects.get` permission, which has been discussed above.

  If you want to know which curated roles already contain the `resourcemanager.projects.get` permission and don't want to craft a complex shell loop, it might be easier to go [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/roles) and filter all roles by `Permission:resourcemanager.projects.get`.

**Note**: if you are running into issues, be sure to read the requirements for granting access to resources [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access).

**Note**: if you are wondering about the `resourcemanager.projects.list` permission, it is only grantable to *organization*-level roles:

```sh
gcloud iam roles create $ROLE \
--description="$ROLE_DESCRIPTION" \
--permissions=resourcemanager.projects.list \
--project=$PROJECT_ID \
--title='$ROLE_TITLE'

#=>

ERROR: (gcloud.iam.roles.create) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Permission resourcemanager.projects.list is not valid.
```

More on this limitation [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-custom-roles#known_limitations).

Answer (score 0):

set new sv account as active in terminal:

```
gcloud config set account  cloud-sql-sv-account@xyz.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Then authenticate using this sv account:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=<path to json sv key>
```